# Why does Chrome Web Store throws an error while publishing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed the chrome extension that works fine in development mode but when i try to publish the same in web store it throws me an error but does not tell anything about the error or what causes it. Moreover in development mode i have a TypeError but the extension works can this TypeError be the reason behind the publish error or is there anything else that i am missing.

I am using a t [this](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) jQuery library for QR code generation & the TypeError i am getting is this

> Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: jQuery(...).qrcode is not a function

here is the manifest.JSON file

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2, 
    "name" : "URL scanner",
    "description" : "scan QR code to open the site on your mobile",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "author" : "Hadi Mir",
    "icons" : {
        "128" : "icon.png",
        "48" : "icon.png",
        "16" : "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
      ],
        "background" : {
            "scripts" : ["./jquery-3.3.1.min.js","background.js"]
        },
        "browser_action" : {
            "default_icon" : "icon.png",
            "default_popup" : " index.html",
            "default_title" : "click to see QR code"
        }
 


}
```

here is the background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
      jQuery('#qrcodeCanvas').qrcode({
        text : tabs[0].url
    }); 
     
});
```

Comment: if you read it clearly i have mentioned that store does not tell me what type of error is this it just tells  "error publishing item"

Comment: I will edit the Question and put the code where it is showing me the TypeError

Comment: I have edited my Question and put both the code and Error in it.

Comment: I think I can help but I need more code. like your menifest.json file code, html file(if you are using button to click the event) and the complete code of the background js file in which you have used the above code.

Comment: ok i will edit my question again

Comment: I think, you need to add *jquery.qrcode.min.js* (like *./jquery-3.3.1.min.js* )in your menifest.json->background-script section so that when the function call for the qrcode() function in background.js code, it will get the function. Also, if you are using onclick to call the function,  you need to apply script tag in html file as defined on https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode

Comment: thanks @Vishal i fixed the bug by adding jquery file and qr code file  to the background script

Comment: Good to Know dear @Hadi Mir :)